# setting a variable in specific type in dictionary

Tags: c#

Ok guys i have a dictionary like so:

```
mControllerTypes = new Dictionary<Type, ControllerBase>() 
{ 
    { Type.Follow, new ControllerFollowTap() },
    { Type.Guide, new ControllerGuide() },
    { Type.Poke, new ControllerPoke() },
    { Type.Swipe, new ControllerSwipe() }
};
```

My problem is  that i want to access and edit a specific variables in the derived types in the dictionary instance. Like lets say in the ControllerSwipe i have a specific variable named SwipeLength which i don't want to include in the base class but want to set it in the dicitionary instance.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((ControllerSwipe)mControllerTypes[Type.Swipe]).SwipeLength = 5;
```